# Wireshark / Tshark pcap reassemble code

Tags: tcp, udp, wireshark, pcap, tshark

Does anybody know where within tshark or wireshark the code is that I could use to reassemble pcap files?  I am working on an app and need to reassemble pcap files, but don't need the other functionality of wireshark / tshark...so, hoping to use this as guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's tcpdump file (not ng format), you can throw away the first 24 bytes (file header) of the second file and concatenate the rest to the first file, then you do the same for all the other files.

Answer (score 0):

mergecap (from wireshark suite) will merge two or more pcap files.